Adding a Header to a GET Request in PolicyCenter Exit Point PCF in Claimcenter
I'm implementing an Exit Point PCF in ClaimCenter to open a URL in a new tab using a GET request. I've set the method to "GET" in the Exit Point PCF, but I also need to include a specific header in the request. Does anyone have suggestions on how to achieve this?

The answer to your specific question is that you cannot inject headers using an Exit Point. But maybe if you add more detail about what you are trying to do then Marty and I would be able to give you better advice. It sounds like you are trying to download or open a document from an external system. Does the document need to be saved to the Document Management System? Does it just need to be viewed and not saved? A little more context would help people to better help you.

@SteveDripps @ Martin Aavik
I have a GET URL that requires a custom header for access. The response from this URL is a PDF file, and I want to display it in a new tab for users to view, rather than downloading it immediately. Initially, I considered using an Exit Point, but I then tried calling the service through a button action. With this approach, I can call the service with the custom header and receive the response as an InputStream. However, I'm unable to open this stream in a new tab—it only downloads the file.

Currently, I'm passing the InputStream to the OOTB function DocumentsUtilBase.renderDocumentContentsWithDownloadDisposition.

I do not think you can add headers with the Exit Point widget. The best you could do would be to add parameters since those can be injected directly into the url String.
So if you are trying to add some authentication headers I think you are out of luck here.

yes this is what i am looking , do we have any other approach we can achieve this ?

I assume the URL you are using in the Exit Point does not use the same SSO credentials that logs the user into the Guidewire application with? Ideally the URL in the Exit Point would send the user to a page that can authenticate them via SSO.

Exit Point PCF  that opens a simple GET URL in a new tab. However, the request requires an additional header attribute with a specific key-value pair. The header key is 'Authorization,' and it needs a specific static value (not a bearer token or any dynamic token)

Yeah I think you are out of luck here unfortunately. I would log a case with Guidewire and note the limitation on the Exit Point widget. I think there are ways to do this using some custom Javascript, but that would for sure not be allowed on a GWCP implementation.

I hope GWCP means it's guidewire cloud?. Also I use. Another approach ,instead for using exit point I use a different approach now . Ie I call the service using Httpget and I created a Document content info object . Then inuse DocumentsUtilBase.renderDocumentContentsWithDowloadDisposition function.  I am able to download the file . However this will not open in next tab but just download the file .

Another option is to not use an ExitPoint.  On the widget (presumably a button?) that is navigating to the exit point, use javascript to orchestrate what you want to do.  That will give you full control of the behavior you need including the ability to inject the header into the http operation.

@MartinAavik  i tried below approach but still no luck                                                          1)used ,  to place my javascript function        2) created a link buttion and in action call that javascript like action =javascript:functionname()''            but still no luck , i am getting error like in browser it is unable to find the javascript function

<![CDATA[
f (xhr.status === 200) {
// Create a new tab and write the response content
var newTab = window.open(); newTab.document.open();newTab.document.write(xhr.responseText);
newTab.document.close();
} else { console.error("Request failed. Status:", xhr.status);}};
// Define what happens in case of an error
xhr.onerror = function() {console.error("Request failed due to a network error.");
};// Send the request    xhr.send();
}]]>

@MartinAavik and i call the javascript function  like action='javascript:openUrlWithHeader()'

Please review the "Client-side Programming" section in the Configuration Guide (under UI Configuration section) for details of how to include custom javascript in your deployment.  I don't see how your use of TemplatePanel is going to work.
